# 'PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied:' when uploading to /media/

Tags: django

I get this error `PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/svr/portfolio/media/projects/2019-09-11_05-13-24.png'` when I try to upload an image to /media/ from the admin panel
I tried `sudo chmod -R 770 /svr` but it makes my entire website unusable due to permissions.

With `sudo chmod -R 755 /svr` it becomes usable again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this by running `chown www-data:www-data -R media`